# Need to get the number of records between 1st occurrence and 2nd occurrence in oracle table

Tags: mysql, oracle

Lets have the below example for reference.

I am having the 'emp' table with below values,

```
Rownumber   Values
1   C21
2   abc\
3   C25
4   C23
5   efg
6   C21
7   abc
8   C25
9   C21
10  ABC


I need the record count between the 1st and 2nd occurrence of C21.
(i.e.,)

Count b/n 1st and 2nd occurrence of 'C21' is = 4

1   C21
2   abc\
3   C25
4   C23
5   efg
6   C21

Count b/n 2nd and 3rd Occurence of 'C21' is  = 2

6   C21
7   abc
8   C25
9   C21
```

Could you please help on the same.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? You tagged both products. Which are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use functions `row_number()` and `lag()`:

```
select val, rn, rn - lag(rn) over (order by rn) - 1 distance
  from ( select row_number() over (order by rnr) rn , rnr, val from emp )
  where val = 'C21'
```

Test data:

```
create table emp(rnr number(3), val varchar2(5));
insert into emp values ( 1, 'C21');
insert into emp values ( 2, 'abc\');
insert into emp values ( 3, 'C25'); 
insert into emp values ( 4, 'C23'); 
insert into emp values ( 5, 'efg');
insert into emp values ( 6, 'C21');
insert into emp values ( 7, 'abc');
insert into emp values ( 8, 'C25');
insert into emp values ( 9, 'C21');
insert into emp values (10, 'ABC');
```

Result:

```
VAL           RN   DISTANCE
----- ---------- ----------
C21            1 
C21            6          4
C21            9          2
```